# variable behavior in javascript, old values doesn't get overridden when using += operator

Tags: javascript

Well i'm afraid that my title doesn't explain it. I'm unable to understand the behavior of variables when they store some values.
i'll try to explain what i'm saying,

**My Code**

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Current Date and Time</title>
  <style>
    p { font: 14px normal arial, verdana, helvetica; }
  </style>
  <script>
    function telltime() {
      var out = "";
      var now = new Date() ;
      out += "<br />Date: " + now.getDate() ;
      out += "<br />Month: " + now.getMonth() ;
      out += "<br />Year: " + now.getFullYear() ;
      out += "<br />Hours: " + now.getHours() ;
      out += "<br />Minutes: " + now.getMinutes() ;
      out += "<br />Seconds: " + now.getSeconds() ;
      document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = out;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  The current date and time are: <br/>
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <script>
    telltime() ;
  </script>
  <input type="button" onclick="location.reload() " value="Refresh" />
</body>
```

it outputs as below:

[image: First Output]

but if i change:

```
  out += "<br />Date: " + now.getDate() ;
  out += "<br />Month: " + now.getMonth() ;
  out += "<br />Year: " + now.getFullYear() ;
  out += "<br />Hours: " + now.getHours() ;
  out += "<br />Minutes: " + now.getMinutes() ;
  out += "<br />Seconds: " + now.getSeconds() ;
```

with this:

```
but if i change:

  out = "<br />Date: " + now.getDate() ;
  out = "<br />Month: " + now.getMonth() ;
  out = "<br />Year: " + now.getFullYear() ;
  out = "<br />Hours: " + now.getHours() ;
  out = "<br />Minutes: " + now.getMinutes() ;
  out = "<br />Seconds: " + now.getSeconds() ;
```

then output would be like this:

[image: 2nd Output]

I'm quiet unable to understand this behavior. up to my understandings a value stored in a variable will always get overridden if we store a new value in that particular variable, no matters the way to store the value, but in case described above, `out` stores all the values which get written when script runs. But if we change `+=` with `=` then `out` only holds the last value which describe current seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because

`out += <br />Date: " + now.getDate()`

means `out = out + "<br />Date: " + now.getDate()`

where as

`out = "<br />Date: " + now.getDate()`

assigns (and overwrites) `output`.

**Update:**

I *think* I now understand where you are getting stuck.

> `out = out + <br />Date: " + now.getDate()` means out gets a new value which is equal to previous value of `out` + some `new value`, so is it not supposed to overwrite the previous `value`?

If you are asking why doesn't the second instance of `out` also get overwritten, then let me explain:

`out = out + "<br />Date: " + now.getDate()`

The `out` *after* the `=` is going to be replaced with `out`'s value at the current time and *then* assigned to `out`.

Comment: i understand this, but where i'm getting confused is that `out = out + <br />Date: " + now.getDate()` means `out` gets a new value which is equal to previous `value of out ` + some new `value`, so is it not supposed to override the previous value?

Comment: I wouldn't say that it "throws away something". It just assigns new value. But thats just the language ;)

Comment: @HassanZia

var x = 5    
var y = 5 + x //10

y += y // y = y + y which is y = 10 + 10

Posting stuff like that doesn't really works in comments :P

Comment: @grzesiekgs mate i know what you are saying, but i'm afraid you ain't getting what i'm saying

Comment: @HassanZia, regarding your first comment, I don't understand where your confusion is.  `out gets a new value which is equal to previous value of out + some new value`.  Yes.  `so is it not supposed to override the previous value` What do you mean by this?

Comment: @HassanZia I am affraid that problem lies in Your way of thinking. If You would **really** understand what I am saying, than You wouldn't ask this question :)

When assign operator is used, Your variable still has unchanged value. The new value is being calculated before actually applying it to variable, and when it is already calculated, then assignment occurs.

Comment: ok i get it, but a little more thing, though i might not be making any sense, why in first case `write` method writes down all the values of out? while it's called only once.. why does it write `day , year, hours, e.t.c` while in the function it's called only once?

Comment: @HassanZia, Good question. This is where your confusion is.  `...writes down all the values of out`.  `out` only gets printed once in **both** examples.  In the first example, the value of out is being added to.  In the second example, the value of out is being overwritten. Keep in mind also that `<br />` is including line breaks for `out`'s single value.  You'll notice that even in the second example, you have a `<br />` after `The current date and time are:`

Comment: that was the actual part where i was getting confused .